# cannot call an object method from a BroadCast listener

Tags: android, sms, broadcast

I have this simple sms listener class:

```
package net.albanx.smspack;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class ReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";        
        ReceiverActivity addtolist = new ReceiverActivity();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);     
                addtolist.addSMS(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(), "now", msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());

                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                       
    }
}
```

I get a null point execption error when the method

```
addtolist.addSMS(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(), "now", msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());
```

is called. This method is part of an activity:

```
public void addSMS(String sms_adress, String sms_date, String message)
{
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // from Number label
    TextView from=new TextView(this);
    from.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    from.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 0));
    from.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),  R.style.from_style);
    from.setText(this.getString(R.string.label_from_sms)+":"+ sms_adress);
    linearLayout.addView(from);
}
```

the problem is at this line:

```
TextView from=new TextView(this);
```

in reference to this that is null.

I am trying to make a sms listener that when a sms is received it updates the list of sms of my running app. It seems that I cannot call an activity method from a broadcast listener. Can any one please explain how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Once again I'll answer this sort of question (and wish I had a dollar for every time I have)...

```
ReceiverActivity addtolist = new ReceiverActivity();
```

You can NOT instantiate an `Activity` using `new`.

`Activity` is a special case in Android and new instances of any class which extends `Activity` can only be created by the Android OS itself. You should never attempt to access any data members or methods of an `Activity` from outside of that `Activity` itself.

If you need to pass data to an `Activity`, then start it using `startActivity(...)` and pass the data via `Intent` extras. Alternatively, nest your `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner class of the `Activity`.

Comment: thank you, I am just a begginer in android but not in java so I tried to do object programing as usual. Just an example how to use startActivity(...) or better to start activity if it is not already started, I tried but I got some errors. Also I am going to do the second alternative. +1 for this (consider it a dollar)

Answer (score 0):

you can not instantiate an Activity using new keyword.so if you want to pass value from broadcast receiver to Activity then use Intent to pass value as:

Pass getOriginatingAddress and getMessageBody to your Activity as:

```
public class ReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
List<String> getOriginatingAddresslist = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> getMessageBodylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";        
        ReceiverActivity addtolist = new ReceiverActivity();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                getOriginatingAddresslist.add(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress());
                getMessageBodylist.add(msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());
            }
         Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class); 
         msgIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("getOriginatingAddresslist", getOriginatingAddresslist); 
         msgIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("getMessageBodylist", getMessageBodylist);  
         startActivity(msgIntent);
```

and in your Activity Receive as:

```
public class YourActivity extends MapActivity 
{
List<String> getOriginatingAddresslist = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> getMessageBodylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        getOriginatingAddresslist = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("getOriginatingAddresslist");  
        getMessageBodylist = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("getMessageBodylist");
        for (int i=0; i<getMessageBodylist.size(); i++){

                addSMS(getOriginatingAddresslist.get(i).toString(), "now", getMessageBodylist.get(i).toString());

            }
```

and for handling new intent if Activity is already running then use o[nNewIntent (Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

or

you can also  use an Custom broadcast receiver for receiving value in Activity from ReceiverListener see

[Custom Intents and Broadcasting with Receivers](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Comment: but actually the problem is not here, it is on the calling the method of activity from listener

Comment: ohh!!! you are creating an instance of Activity and then calling addSMS.then this not right means your Activity is not running ?

Comment: first it's not possible to call addSMS from BroadcastReceiver

Comment: I just learn this. I need to start the activity, or just to have a reference if any activity has been started already